# How to load Spring beans xml configuration from different location in Debug and Release mode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring and Hibernate with a non-web application. I am creating the sessionFactory bean in the /src/main/resources/Hibernate.xml

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
....login, password, etc
```

It is okay, but when I finish some changes I want to create an executable jar file and put it into another server where is different database located. The problem is that I have to open the jar file and change database configuration everytime I create that jar file to make it compatible with external database on the different server.

The solution for this problem would be to load Hibernate.xml from the outside of the jar file.

And here is the question - how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add "file:" prefix.:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="file:config/hibernate.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all that is different between the two environments is the database address and credentials, I'd recommend putting those into a property file and using placeholders in your XML configuration ([docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc)).

You can then either access the property file as classpath resource (In Spring config, use `classpath:` prefix for the file path) that you can configure at runtime, or let your build system copy a different version of the file into the JAR depending on target environment (in Maven, this can be done using [Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)).

Comment: But how can I point to the property file outside of the jar file? When I put     classpath:../config.properties it screams File not found.

Comment: Try `classpath:config.properties`, with your `config.properties` being directly in a folder that's on classpath.

Comment: Not working. I have main.jar and confi.properties in the same dir. I run it via  "java -jar main.jar". Also tried to add -cp ./ and still file not found.